# Tensorflow: How to assign a name to a list of tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I am doing the following code using TF 2 (but working with TF 1 actually):

```
self.gradients_w, self.gradients_b = tf.gradients(ys=self.loss, xs=[self.w, self.b])
self.training_op_w = tf.compat.v1.assign(self.w, self.w - self.learning_rate * self.gradients_w)
self.training_op_b = tf.compat.v1.assign(self.b, self.b - self.learning_rate * self.gradients_b)
self.training_op = tf.stack([self.training_op_w, self.training_op_b], axis=0, name="training_op")
```

Basically I will like to have this `training_op` as a list of all the assignments so then by only doing `self.sess.run(self.training_op, feed_dict=feed_dict_batch)` I train my whole network as once. When I have multiple layers I will then create a longer list and the training part of the code will remain untouched.

This works so far, the problem comes when I try to restore the networks metadata. Because the list is not saved as a single tensorflow name so I have to get each one of them then loosing the generality/flexibility I want. So my question is:

**How to assign a name to a list of tensors?**

I tried some things like [tf.stack()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) or [tf.convert_to_tensor()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) but I have error messages telling me the sizes don't match (which they won't). Example:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
    From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'leargning_rule/training_op' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [30,1], [1].
```

Comment: why not do something like setting the trainable variable?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a stack of these various layers, just define them under the same scope, for example the scope "train_specific", like this:

```
with tf.name_scope("train_specific"):
    self.gradients_w, self.gradients_b = tf.gradients(ys=self.loss, xs=[self.w, self.b])
    self.training_op_w = tf.compat.v1.assign(self.w, self.w - self.learning_rate * self.gradients_w)
    self.training_op_b = tf.compat.v1.assign(self.b, self.b - self.learning_rate * self.gradients_b)
    self.training_op = tf.stack([self.training_op_w, self.training_op_b], axis=0, name="training_op")
```

then you may get the list of ops under this scope by using `tf.get_collection()` as such

```
tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="train_specific")
```

Refer to: [tf.get_collection](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/get_collection)

Comment: Well, I didn't managed to make it work, the function returned me always an empty list (I double checked the spelling). However it gave me an idea. I used `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_operations()` and check for names starting with "train_specific" and did my list with that... It's a bit horrible but works for now.

Comment: thats great if it worked, i was gonna suggest that at the start, but thought this was more natural

Comment: And apologies its my mistake, we should have defined it with `tf.variable_scope` not `tf.name_scope`, maybe that was the issue, not sure though

Comment: I will give it a try this afternoon. If it works I will mark you answer as the solution. However you should edit your answer to correct the mistake.

Comment: if it works, then ill edit it, no use otherwise i suppose

Comment: I believe it didn't worked :S mmmm strange... I mean, looking at the documentation all you say makes sense, I might be doing something wrong somewhere. I will come back when I figure it out